# How to add texture to a file with typescript and three.js

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can someone help me please? I followed a tutorial on this website which is the result i want :
https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdkbundle_tutorials_models.html

First thing first, can you confirm me which language is used ? I think this is typescript and three.js internally.
So I need to put textures on objects, but I don't know how to do it. The objects are in .obj, .fbx or .dae.
To add an object to the scene I do this :

```
const modelNode = await sdk.Scene.createNode();
const fbxComponent = modelNode.addComponent(sdk.Scene.Component.FBX_LOADER, {
    url:'https://gitcdn.link/repo/Raffy101/Pour-importer-fichier-obj/main/objets/Armchair.FBX',
});
fbxComponent.inputs.localScale = {
    x: 0.01,
    y: 0.01,
    z: 0.01
  };

 modelNode.obj3D.position.setX(-5);
 modelNode.obj3D.position.setZ(-5); 
 modelNode.obj3D.position.setY(0);

 modelNode.start();
```

I don't know if I have been understood. Sorry these things are new to me. And excuse me for my english.
Thank you

Comment: https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/ check this out .BTW it says its build on Javascript

Comment: can you add this in a jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dh9xw7y2/#&togetherjs=O0SntgdPp4 
ok here it is but i don't know if it'll work because i use a command to compile :" yarn start"

Comment: why don't you clone the repository where they have given examples and try to run over there

Comment: I tried but it's not free, i need a special key to make some example work

Comment: if it is a paid version signup and try for free or it will be best to write a mail to them to get some mock credentials

Comment: I already have a key, indeed I can add an object to the scene like the example. As a result, I don't think I need to pay to add textures. Also there is a special key to use the sandbox version but it doesn't matter for me.